# Why doesn't Flask use my custom json_encoder?

Tags: python, json, flask

I have the following application and test:

**app.py**

```
from json import JSONEncoder                                                       
from flask import Flask, jsonify                                                   

class CustomJSONEncoder(JSONEncoder):                                              
    def default(self, obj):                                                        
        return {"hello": "world"}                                                  


app = Flask(__name__)                                                              
app.json_encoder = CustomJSONEncoder                                               


@app.route('/')                                                                    
def main():                                                                        
    return jsonify({'yep': 'this worked'})                                         


if __name__ == '__main__':                                                         
    app.run()
```

**test_app.py**

```
import json                                                                     
from app import app                                                             


def test_this_should_work():                                                    
    test_client = app.test_client()                                             

    rv = test_client.get('/')                                                   

    assert json.loads(rv.data.decode()) == {'hello': 'world'}
```

As best as I can tell from [this example](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/119/), my code should work and return this other dictionary. However, it doesn't. You can run it via `python app.py` or `py.test` (if you install py.test), and you'll observe that both times return `{"yep": "this worked"}`.

Something is wrong here - what am I missing?

Comment: Haven't you forgot a to add `return JSONEncoder.default(self, {"hello": "world"})` at the end of your `CustomJSONEncoder` instead `{"hello": "world"}`?

Comment: Why not just monkey patch `flask.json.jsonify`? Set the default of `JSONEncoder` to a function of your choosing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not an issue with Flask, [which does send the custom encoder](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/0.10-maintenance/flask/json.py#L97).  It's just the way Python's json library works.  The `default` function is only called if the object being dumped is not recognized.  Since you're dumping a string, which is a type recognized by the library, it's just dumped as is.

If you want to transform your data, do the transformation before serializing it.

---

[This recently came up on the Flask issue tracker as well.](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/issues/1443)